# mariadb stored procedure scope query cache bug

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Have you encountered case like that:

Inside mariadb stored procedure I select rows from table for example with parameters:

```
Table some_table
------------------
id | field1 | field2 | user | status
1  | xxx    | yyy    | 333  | 2
```

---

```
select field1 into field1_variable from some_table 
where user_id=333 and status=1;
```

If that query returns null i.e. field1_variable is null then any cursor after execution of query above with query like that:

```
select field1,field2 from another_table
left join some_table on another_table.user_id=some_table.user_id 
where user_id=333;
```

Will not select any row because previous query with more parameters (status=1) returned null.

As far as I move first query in outer function everything works.

My best guess is that MariaDB 10 has some bug in which it evaluates some stored procedure scope query cache and does it incorrectly within judging that if previous query containing same table and part of same search criteria - returned null than next query should not even be executed.

I fill very silly writing this but I ve spent half day dealing with that case before day of production when I have time I ll provide reproducible scenario of that bug if it is bug at all.

Comment: If this question is on MariaDB, the sql-server and mysql tags should not be in the post. Please use tags properly, so your question goes to the right target.

Comment: as mariadb was based on mysql repository I thought people might experience this rarest situation in mysql also possibly

Comment: OK, I add mysql tag, sql-server was invalid as it is Microsoft SQL Server. thank you for letting me know.

Comment: You need to show us a little more code, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  What makes you suspect the Query cache?  Why do you have the QC on at all?